# how to redirect to external url from view? Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to redirect my image when it clicked.. so here is my code in view

```
<a href="www.accorhotels.com" class="work-ext-link">
```

but its always error with the route, is there any solution to directly go to that website without using route and controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "http" before:

```
<a href="http://www.accorhotels.com" class="work-ext-link">my link</a>
```